# how can I make the background of the Tiled map transparent? (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I want to put a background image to my game, I want to first draw the image and then render the map, the problem is that the map has a black background so the image cannot be seen, how can I make the background color of the map become transparent?

I can't put it as a image layer in Tiled map, becouse it lose quality.

Comment: Where is the black background coming from? Can´t you just simply change it to something transparent (by editing the tiledmap) ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to express with `iit loses quality`?. A one colored image shoulnd`t have that problem as scaling it does basically nothing to the content.

Comment: Are your tiles transparent?

Comment: i resolve the problem i had badly positioned renderer.render method